# Are changes to El Capitan's SIP configuration file persistent?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, sudo, osx-el-capitan

If you toggle System Integrity Protection off to tweak some things, unload daemons, delete apps, etc., will those changes survive toggling SIP back on and re-launching the machine, or will the changes be reverted?

[This review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/9/), based on OS 10.11 beta, suggests that deleting certain apps like Chess.app did not give the system any hiccups. But would this behavior be different for changing launch agents or launch daemons behavior? What about editing `defaults`? If one is accustomed to using "dotfiles," will those changes persist or will some of them revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, it seems that changes are persistent.

My experience has been that disabling SIP lasts for only one reboot; i.e., you disable SIP via command terminal in OS Recovery mode and reboot the machine, and the SIP will be disabled for that session. SIP will remain disabled even if the computer is put to sleep. However, SIP will re-enable itself following a second shutdown or restart. Whatever changes you make during the period SIP is disabled will persist. The changes you make will also persist after updating, e.g., from 10.11.1 to 10.11.2.